# How to discover through javascript that wcf rest service is stop or not hosted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf, rest

Created 1 wcf Rest service which return JSON data. Through Javascrip/Jquery (without Asp.net)
want to get status that service is stop or not deploy on localhost.

Tried this :

```
var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', "http://host/MP4Convertor%20v1.0.0.0/service.svc/CheckServiceStatus", true);  

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4||xmlhttp.readyState == 0) {
    //alert("Ready state: " + xmlhttp.readyState.toString());
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //alert("good");
        alert("Response: " +xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    if (xmlhttp.status !=200){
        //alert("bad");
        alert("Error: " +xmlhttp.status.toString() +"  response text:  " +xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
} else {
    alert("readystate bad");
}
 }

xmlhttp.send(null); 


and another approach: 

    $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "http://host/MP4Convertor%20v1.0.0.0/service.svc/CheckServiceStatus?method=callback",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            error: function (data) {
                alert("list failed!");
            },
            success: function (list) {
                alert(list); // must call function as var
            }
       });
```

But in both case if service is start or stop in always falls in error case

Can any one Please suggest preferable solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: So actually when you get error from this service, can it be considered as the service is not working?

Comment: Error can be for any internal reason also so can no count upon that.